# How does whats app login work on iphone..?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, addressbook

I am just curious and wanted to know how does what's app show list of all friends..? I mean once you login into the app with your phone number does it get all the contacts phone number from Address book and send it to server (Is this ok to do ? can apple reject your app if you access someone's contact list and transfer all the data to your server?)

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp#Technical_specifics see this link for the info

Answer (score 3):

Yes, whats app do send all your contact list to server which then returns who have installed whats app. 
Apple wont reject your application since this is the way how it works.

But prefer encrypting contact list when you send to server.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20971813).

> WhatsApp looks at the phone numbers in your address book, then checks to see which of those numbers are registered in WhatsApp. This allows any WhatsApp users from your address book to appear as contacts in your Favorites / Select contact screen and Chats.